Implementing a Meta Transaction Relayer with Separate Gas Fee and Worldcoin Wallets on Worldchain
What changes should I make to my code to create a Meta Transaction Relayer that pays the gas fee with an ETH wallet (on the Worldchain network) different from the one sending the Worldcoin (on the Worldchain network)?
class WorldChain {
    async transfer(address, amount, privateKey) {
        try {
            const RPC_URL = process.env.ETHEREUM_RPC_URL;
            const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x2cFc85d8E48F8EAB294be644d9E25C3030863003";
            const ABI_TRANSFER = [
                "function balanceOf(address owner) view returns (uint256)",
                "function decimals() view returns (uint8)",
                "function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) public returns (bool)"
            ];

            const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider(RPC_URL);
            const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(privateKey, provider);
                
            const wldContract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, ABI_TRANSFER, wallet);
            const balance = await wldContract.balanceOf(wallet.address);                
            const decimals = await wldContract.decimals();

            const ethBalance = await provider.getBalance(wallet.address);
            console.log("balance of ETH in wei:", ethBalance.toString());
            const formattedBalance1 = ethers.formatUnits(ethBalance, "ether");
            console.log("Formatted ETH balance:", formattedBalance1);

            const formattedBalance = ethers.formatUnits(balance, decimals).replace('.', ',');

            console.log(`Current Worldcoin balance: ${formattedBalance} WLD`);

            const amountInWei = ethers.parseUnits(amount, decimals); 

            const gasEstimate = await provider.estimateGas({
                to: address,
                data: wldContract.interface.encodeFunctionData('transfer', [address, amountInWei]),
            });
            console.log("Gas estimate: ", gasEstimate.toString());


            const tx = await wldContract.transfer(address, amountInWei, {
                gasLimit: (Number(gasEstimate) + 100000).toString(), 
            });
            console.log(`Transaction sent: ${tx.hash}`);

            await tx.wait();
            console.log(`Transaction received: ${tx.hash}`)

            return {
                status: 'success',
                transactionHash: tx.hash
            };  
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
            return {
                status: 'error',
                error: error.message
            };
        }
    }
}

